# Vulkan Validation Layer keeps throwing an Image Layout Error on VkQueuePresentKHR()

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

Obvious noob warning. Been learning Vulkan since yesterday, and as the title says, I keep getting the above error on submitting to present. I've checked the code from the tutorial but can't find any obvious error. Here is my RenderPass creation code:

```
VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachmentDescription = {};
    colorAttachmentDescription.format = this->surfaceFormat.format;
    colorAttachmentDescription.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    colorAttachmentDescription.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    colorAttachmentDescription.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    colorAttachmentDescription.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachmentDescription.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachmentDescription.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    colorAttachmentDescription.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;


    VkAttachmentReference attachmentReference = {};
    attachmentReference.attachment = 0;
    attachmentReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;


    VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription = {};
    subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &attachmentReference;
    subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;


    VkSubpassDependency subpassDependency = {};
    subpassDependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    subpassDependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    subpassDependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
    subpassDependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    subpassDependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    subpassDependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;


    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo = {};
    renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = &colorAttachmentDescription;
    renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
    renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = &subpassDependency;


    vkCreateRenderPass(logicalDevice, &renderPassCreateInfo, nullptr, &renderPass);
```

Oh and I've even tried changing the initialLayout to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` but still get the error. This is the validation Layer error that I get.

```
VALIDATION LAYER : Images passed to present must be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR but is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pImageIndices must be the index of a presentable image acquired from the swapchain specified by the corresponding element of the pSwapchains array, and the presented image subresource must be in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR layout at the time the operation is executed on a VkDevice (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296)
```

Comment: "*I've even tried changing the initialLayout to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR but still get the error*" Why do you think specifying present as the pre-renderpass layout would in any way affect the layout of the image at present time?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Yeah, it wouldn't.

Comment: I'm guessing that the error isn't in the code you've pasted, but that you're somehow attempting to present an image without ever executing this renderpass against it.  If you can create a complete, self-contained example, you can put it on Gist and other people can probably get a better idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the render pass creation omitted from your posted code.

Double check [VkAttachmentDescription](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkAttachmentDescription.html) entries in the [VkRenderPassCreateInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkRenderPassCreateInfo.html).

Also check if the `attachmentCount` is not zero.